# How to change background color of top and bottom side of tableview?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I changed tableview cell color. But when I move to up or down side of tableview, it is still white. How can I change that empty space color programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a different color of table and cell, just say `tableView.backgroundColor = desiredColor`.  The `UIColor` class offers class methods like `+blueColor`, `+redColor`, and such.

If you want the same color of the table and its cells, keep the code above and add this in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
// Customize the cell
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
for (UIView *subview in [cell subviews]) {
    subview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

This is a better solution than simply saying `cell.backgroundColor = desiredColor` because if you decide to use a view (such as a pattern), instead of just a color, as the background of your table, the background will be visible at all times, not just when you bounce the content.

Answer (score 0):

`tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor]`